# Regulating Negative Voltage

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, negative-voltage

Can the [TL783](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl783.pdf) be used to regulate negative voltage by connecting the output to my system ground and using the regulator ground as my negative voltage source? I couldn't find anything in the datasheet pertaining to negative regulation except something like this:

> The device works to keep the voltage at the OUT pin 1.25
>   V higher than the voltage at the ADJ pin. Therefore, a resistor divider can be used to set the output voltage.

This would lead me to believe it should work as I described, but I'd like to verify with someone who knows more than me about this.

Comment: this could work, but it's easy to mess up, specially if your circuit also needs positive supplies. If you post a schematic and details about the loads we can give a better answer

Answer (score 1):

> Can the TL783 be used to regulate negative voltage by connecting the output to my system ground and using the regulator ground as my negative voltage source?

Yes. BUT!

You must ensure that the unregulated voltage is isolated from system ground, and the ONLY connection to ground is made at the regulator output.

Generally, this means a separate transformer winding dedicated to your negative supply. Rectification and filtering must also be careful not to inadvertantly make connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the ground of the load to be the same net as the ground of your input power source, it won't work. In your proposed circuit the regulator can only dump more or less current from a positive supply into the ground net. It doesn't have any way to control the current drawn from the load's negative terminal.

What you want is a negative linear regulator. LM7905 is a low-cost one for -5 V. LM337 is a low-cost adjustable output one.

You will also need an input power supply more negative than the voltage you want to apply to your load.

Comment: But since it's negative voltage, wouldn't there be no current drawn from the negative terminal, only sunk into it?

Comment: Drawn out of the load's negative terminal. Sunk into the supply's terminal.

Comment: Possibly not true - this sort of scheme can work if you have two separate (unregulated) power supplies and treat them as a series connection of power supplies. The middle node is then ground. Granted it's probably easier and cheaper to pick up a 790x and design it properly...

Comment: @awjlogan, edited.

Comment: I can find an input supply more negative than what I need for output. The problem is I need to regulate about -100V down to about -60V (at very low current), way out of spec for the 7905

Comment: If the current is low, and the headroom is large (like you have) it's not too difficult to make your own linear regulator. Take the circuit diagram from page 1 of the TLV783 that you linked and flip it around for negative voltages. If you get stuck, you can ask a new question. (Trick will be picking a good op-amp or designing a difference amp to work with -100 V supply)

Comment: If the current is really tiny, you can just use the op-amp itself to buffer (or multiply) a reference voltage.

Comment: @BillyKalfus: "*I need to regulate about -100V down to about -60V*". This is essential information in your original question. Why did you waste so much of people's time by leaving it out? Please edit your question to contain all the relevant information.

Comment: @BillyKalfus and what "very low current"? That is essential information too. Most high voltage transistors work at low currents, so we need to know what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

TL783 does not work with negative voltage.

LM7905, LM337 do not meet your voltage requirment.

How about [LM137HVQML](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs314a/snvs314a.pdf)?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. The OP is asking about using the positive voltage regulator in standard configuration but grounding the positive output. That would make what's usually the 0 V rail into a negative.